# Repeating print output for all lines read

Tags: python, python-3.x, repeat

```
        import sys

    def main():
        global dna
        dna = {}
        chromo = []
        position = []

        parseFile(sys.argv[1], dna, chromo, position)       

    def parseFile(raw_file, dna, chromo, position): 
        raw_filename    = raw_file
        raw_file        = open(raw_filename, 'r')
        raw_lines       = raw_file.readlines()
        raw_file.close()

        for line in raw_lines:  
            dna_info = line.split('\t') # splitting by tab
            dna_info[-1] = dna_info[-1][:-1] # getting rid of new line

            rsid = dna_info[0]
            genotype = dna_info[3]
            dna[rsid] = dna_info[3] 

            checkType2Diabetes(dna_info, rsid, genotype)    

    **def checkType2Diabetes(dna_info, rsid, genotype):

        for item in rsid: 
            if "rs7754840" in rsid:
                print ("Key Found")
                break 
            else:
                print("No Key Found")**
```

Whole code included, problem in def checkType2Diabetes(etc..) 
I want the code to only print once, but for each key it checks, it prints if the key is not found. Which, when I run a file full of rsid #s, the output is:

```
    No Key Found
    No Key Found
    No Key Found
    No Key Found
```

(continue for all lines in txt)

But if it is not found, all I want is

```
    No Key Found
```

Comment: Dedent the `else` and the `print` one tab, so that the `else` aligns with `for` rather than `if`.

Comment: [Documentation to the above statement](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) (Thanks @Zirak for the link). TIL

Answer (score 0):

We need a clear description of data and functionality.  I *think* that your problem is misuse of the for iteration, but I can't be certain.

It looks like rsid is a field of each record, containing an ID string.  However, your last for loop assumes it's something to be taken apart.  For instance, if rsid has the value "rs7754840" from the input line, that for loop iterates through the individual characters: 'r', 's', '7', '7', etc.

In this case, what you need at the bottom of the loop is mode like this:

```
        rsid = dna_info[0]
        genotype = dna_info[3]
        dna[rsid] = dna_info[3] 

        if "rs7754840" in rsid:
            print ("Key Found")
            break

    else:
        print("No Key Found")
```

Note an important point: the **else** here is on the **for** loop, not on the **if**.  The logic problem you have is that if the ID is in the records somewhere, you know as soon as you find it.  If it isn't, you don't know until you drop out of the loop.  You tried to do it all at once, and that's why you got "No key found" printed repeatedly.

Does this get you moving?

Comment: We were reading it large files of DNA data - using the rsid as a key for a dictionary to find a genotype value to print out genetic tendencies. This was a lead up - simply trying to see if the key existed in the dictionary. But your fix worked, thanks.

Comment: It's great to hear that you're making progress!  Please remember to "accept" an answer, or do something else to close this question.